# AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

First I have successfully completed configuring my react application using `amplify configure`. I did that with the help of [AWS Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install). Then I have successfully added authentication to my amplify project, using `amplify add auth` and `amplify push`. I followed all the steps in the [AWS - Authentication with Amplify Doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js)

My `App.js` looks like this,

```
import React from 'react';
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);


const App = () => (
    <div>
        <AmplifySignOut />
        My App
    </div>
);

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

But when I try `npm start`, it shows the following error,
[image: AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.]

Answer (score 61):

I found the solution to this problem in this [github-issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4315)

The fix was simple. Amplify docs do not tell you to load configs of `aws-exports` to `Auth module`.

Adding this simple line of code in `App.js`, solved the issue for me.

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

// >>New - Configuring Auth Module
Auth.configure(awsconfig);
```

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the issue for me as well. Possible that this is new in an updated version of amplify as I had amplify auth working flawlessly before and the issue arose after upgrading aws-amplify.

Comment: spent hours on identifying it. This one worked awesomly.

Comment: In my case I had to reinstall the dependencies for it to work (`npm un aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react` / `npm i aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react`)

Comment: what awsconfig equals to?

Comment: Awesome, this saved me!

Comment: This saved my Vue 3 + Vite project, too! Thanks! Here's my code in progress. I will still be adding data storage, etc from a PluralSight tutorial. https://github.com/dolthead/aws-amplify-vue-vite

Answer (score 16):

- npm un aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react
- npm i aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react

This worked for me. Thanks @Ignacio

Comment: This worked for me. I had "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.24" and "aws-amplify": "^3.3.4".

Answer (score 15):

I think this problem occurs under various Amplify module versions due to inconsistencies between installed Amplify modules.
In my cases, reinstalling as the below solved it many times.

`npm uninstall --save aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react @aws-amplify/ui-components`

`npm install --save aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react @aws-amplify/ui-components`

There is a case that needs reinstalling *@aws-amplify/ui-components* if you use it.

Comment: This worked for me. No need to import 'Auth' module and/or do Auth.configure()

Answer (score 5):

I was doing todo app in Expo,and faced same issue.
I had to add right path for config file. Path is different for `aws-exports` and it is not mentioned in Docs.
My example code is below

```
import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
Auth.configure(awsconfig);

import { createTodo } from './src/graphql/mutations'
import { listTodos } from './src/graphql/queries'
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Yarn, this issue can arise from a package manager conflict based on how they manage the dependency tree and version updates.

If you are seeing this issue repeatedly; In some scenarios you should try using Npm.

> If you are using Yarn -You should first delete Yarn.lock and your node_modules directory.
> npm install

Also, see the answer above too [Untamables Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649233/1664389)

Comment: What's the issue with Yarn ? it wont just work with Yarn is it ?

Answer (score 2):

run amplify update auth

choose Walkthrough all the auth configurations.

enable unauthenticated logins along the walkthrough and leave other settings.

Source: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js/#using-amplify-graphql-client

When using AWS_IAM for public API access, unauthenticated logins must be enabled. To enable unauthenticated logins, run amplify update auth from the command line and choose Walkthrough all the auth configurations.

this solved my problem in combination with graphQL API

Answer (score 1):

If your component is is SSR then change it to client mode.
I was using NextJS, layout.tsx is main file in it.

```
layout.tsx
-------------------
import "./globals.css";

import type { Metadata } from "next";

import { Alegreya } from "next/font/google";

import Main from "../components/main";

const inter = Alegreya({ subsets: ["greek"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Todo App",
  description: "Todo App For Event Management!",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Main>{children}</Main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In layout.tsx the Main component is not using 'use client' at top of the file so I had to add it.

```
main.tsx
-----------------------------
"use client"; // added this for client side rendering
// server side rendering gives Auth error.

import React from "react";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";

import awsConfig from "@/aws-config";
import Footer from "@/components/footer";
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import TodoProvider from "@/contexts/TodoProvider";

Amplify.configure(awsConfig);

const Main = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <TodoProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="pt-16 lg:mx-36 md:mx-24 sm:mx-14 mx-3">
          <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </TodoProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

I do not know the reason, after lots of research to find solution I found it in a github issue and there was no explantion. If anyone knows why? let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with this error right now without having @aws-amplify/ui-react installed. I believe there were changes made to Auth from version 3 to 4 that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are following a tutorial here are some precautions that might be helpful to you and save you same headache.
Use modules and dependencies that the tutor of the tutorial is using. Do not assume anything.

in package.json file write the dependencies and version as guided by the tutorial and at the end dont run npm install.
why? npm install pops up ERR errors that are headaches. Use yarn install and it will fix your errors.

e.g
in my project's package.json file i have the following::
{

"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.9-unstable.12",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.32.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.26",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.1",
    "stripe": "^9.10.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
}


from the guide of the tutorial.But from react all these dependencies are old some obsolete. What do i do? I dont install each individual to bring confusion in modules by just running yarn install to align them and erradicet errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can appear due to a misconfiguration of the Amplify CLI. That was the case for me.
Run `amplify configure` and follow the instructions.

Comment: the error in the OP, is found in the console of the browser. it has nothing to do with the setup of the cli.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed some lines in the aws-exports file, or you assign env variable inside the file, it can may block the configuration.
Make sure your aws-export file as in generated form.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this error when trying to use {Auth} in a nextJs server component, you must also include it on the server level as per the docs. In my case I only had it declared in the client layout.

```
Example Next.js App Router Client Component containing your login flow (e.g. app/page.tsx):

'use client';

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from '@/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

export default function Home() {
  return {
    /* Render a login form for your users */
  };
}

Example Next.js App Router Server Component (e.g. app/posts/page.tsx):

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from '@/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

export default async function Page() {
  // ...
}
```