# New AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I'm getting the following error when running my angular applicationT:

> Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
> This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:
>
> 1. Make sure you're passing the awsconfig object to Amplify.configure() in your app's entry point
>    See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#configure-your-app for more information
> 2. There might be multiple conflicting versions of aws-amplify or amplify packages in your node_modules.
>    Try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies with `yarn install`

One strange thing is that this happens only with `--prod` enabled.

It was fine until today, Sept 9th, but I don't know which package version is causing the issue. I already tried using the older ones from aws-amplify and aws-amplify-angular, but it seems to be other package. How could I know which one?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "proyect",
  "version": "0.5.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --buildOptimizer=true --optimization=true --prod=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.7",
    "aws-amplify-angular": "^5.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.5.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: I wrote answer in other issue. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77421323/21402581](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77421323/21402581)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found a solution that I never saw anywhere, more related to my code editor (Webstorm) I guess.

Context:
I renamed my aws-export.js to .ts, as recommanded in Amplify:

> Depending on your TypeScript version you may need to rename aws-exports.js to aws-exports.ts prior to importing, or enable the allowJs compiler option in your tsconfig.

When I got the famous error, I noticed that my aws-export.ts didn't have any Auth property, and "contain" another file :

[image]

The .js version was well updated with everything, so I took its content to copy-past in my .ts version, and It's working.

Comment: That was the solution for me too. Everyone says the solution above but I bet this is the correct one

Comment: Currently on `aws-amplify 4.3.19`, can confirm that this works for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `Auth.configure(params)` missing in your code.

pass the same params that you use for `Amplify.configure(params)`

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same situation. In my application I'm using only Auth component, so I have to add Auth.configure()

```
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure(environment.amplify);
// The following code-line solved the issue
Auth.configure(environment.amplify);
```

Thanks to author of https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5429