# Amplify says not configured correctly after days of use

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been building an AWS amplify app for days. I've been logged in to my app while doing this. Today, I believe that the login expired and now, I am getting the error :

```
[ERROR] 37:22.581 AuthError - 
        Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
        This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

        1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
            See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

        2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

I don't understand this. The app has been working. I was logged in. I was adding data to tables through the app. I haven't changed anything about the auth (though I have changed the schema for graphql and pushed that).

When I do an amplify push, it tells me that there are no changes. I have no idea what to do now?

Comment: Hi, have you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605779/autherror-error-amplify-has-not-been-configured-correctly